# Gitlab change from only/except to rules for control ci, what will be alternative for it

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Recently Git-lab change only/except to rules. so if i have below only in my .gitlab-ci.yaml, what will be equivalent rules for it.

```
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - triggers
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#rules) like this :

```
rules:
 - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "trigger" || $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
   when: on_success
```